# I want to remove text to the right of a single character in a text string

Tags: excel

Can anyone answer in a non techy format please. I have text in column A1 (Myname : Someone). I want to copy the rightmost text starting from the colon,(someone), and inserting into cell B1. I am not the least technical, so would appreciate an idiots answer. Thanks.

I have read all the answers I think pertain to this, but don't understand any of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula for text in A1

`=TRIM(REPLACE(A1,1,FIND(":",A1),""))`

that replaces everything up to and including the colon with "" (nothing) and then uses TRIM to remove any superfluous spaces

Comment: This formula works exactly the way I want. Thankyou!

Comment: I would if I knew how. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I do not have enough rep to add comment, that is why I am writing as answer. Did you consider using text to column function? After selecting whole column, go to "Data" tab, there is a function called Text to Column. In that you can simply select "Delimited" and then in the next screen you can input ":" as other delimiter.

Answer (score -1):

If you want the "someone" just paste this code in B1:

```
=RIGHT(A1;FIND(":";A1))
```

It looks for the ":" and cuts the string from that character to the right (with spaces). If you want to remove the spacing add trim():

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(A1;FIND(":";A1)))
```

Edit because of @pnuts advice:
If you want the left side of the text:

```
=TRIM(LEFT(A1;FIND(":";A1)-1))
```

And if your delimiter is `,` instead of `;` then change all the `;` to `,`

Comment: @pnuts He says he wants to copy the rightmost text into cell B1?

Comment: The first formula doesn't work consistently because you are defining the number of characters required (to the right) by the position of the : from the left - what happens if Text in A1 = `Myname:Abe` ?